# Calcinai Xero-PHP and the Payroll AU SuperFund endpoint

Tags: php, arrays, xero-api

Using the calcinai Xero-PHP library from https://github.com/calcinai/xero-php

I have an onboarding form I'm making where a new employee puts all their details in, signs it, and submits it. On submission it sends all their details to Xero.

I can get all the personal and bank account details sent over properly but I'm having no luck figuring out how to add the employee's super.

From what I can tell, I need to get the SuperFundID to be able to create the employee's SuperFundMembership. So I've been trying to use `$xero->load('\\XeroPHP\\Models\\PayrollAU\\SuperFund')`

Tried: `$xero->load('\\XeroPHP\\Models\\PayrollAU\\SuperFund')->where("ABN", [an ABN])->execute()`: Doesn't work because apparently according to the Xero console/history "ABN property is not supported for Where or Order clause" even though the documentation at https://developer.xero.com/documentation/payroll-api/superfunds says I can "Filter by an any element "

Tried: `$xero->load('\\XeroPHP\\Models\\PayrollAU\\SuperFund')->setParameter("ABN", "65714394898")->execute();` which send a request `[url]superfunds?ABN=65714394898` and returns a Collection object with ALL the SuperFunds stored in my Xero as a `[storage:ArrayObject:private] => Array (a private array of SuperFund objects)`. Given my novice PHP skills I don't know how to then get the super fund I'm after or how to access that array. Also, it doesn't seem very efficient to me to get ALL of the super funds when I'm only after one. Performing the load...execute action without the setParameter clause returns the same array of everything.

About ready to give up but I know there's something stupidly obvious I'm not doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You for some reason have to load a list of ALL of the SuperFunds, and loop through them to find the right one.

```
// Given a USI, try to find and return Xero's ID of the SuperFund
function findIDByUSI(&$xero, $usi)
{
    $funds[] = $xero->load('\\XeroPHP\\Models\\PayrollAU\\SuperFund')->execute();
    foreach($funds[0] as $fund)
    {
        if($fund->getUSI() == $usi)
            return $fund->getSuperFundID();
    }
    return null;
}
```

If if doesn't exist you can try and create it, and then get its ID.